# Evaluate and resolve a promise in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift3, promise, wkwebview

This is sums up all iOS developing i have ever done. So I'm very new to swift or any iOS developing for that matter.

What I'm trying to accomplish is something that behaves almost like jsonp when doing cross domain ajax request in javascript (if you know how that works...)

I have a problem in that I can't evaluate javascript and get back something that behaves is asynchronous. For example getting anything from the indexedDB in the webview

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after lvaring the view, typically from a nib.
    self.webview = WKWebView()
    self.i = 0

    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

    configuration.preferences = preferences
    configuration.userContentController.add(self as WKScriptMessageHandler,name: "bridge")

    self.webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: configuration)
    webview.navigationDelegate = self
    webview.isHidden = true
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.com")!))

    /* 
    help...
    don't know how closure & completion Handler (callbacks) works in swift
    runjs("Promise.resolve({msg: 'hello world'})", completionHandler: (result) -> Void) {
        print(result) // expecting it to be {msg: 'hello world'}
    })
    */
}
```

My helper function

```
func runjs(input: String, completeHandler: Any) {
    self.i = self.i + 1
    // TODO: store the completeHandler in a some HashMap with `i` as the key

    let js = "Promise.resolve(" + input + ").then(res => webkit.messageHandlers.bridge.postMessage({i: " + String(self.i) + ", data: res}))"

    webview.evaluateJavaScript(js)
}
```

My message handler

```
/// Adds support for the WKScriptMessageHandler to ViewController.
extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController,
                               didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        let json:NSDictionary = message.body as! NSDictionary
        let i:Int = json["i"] as! Int
        let data:NSDictionary = json["data"] as! NSDictionary

        // TODO: get the complete handler from a HashMap[i]
        // TODO: call the complete handler with data as argument
        // TODO: remove the complete handler from the HashMap
    }
}
```

Comment: got any solution?

Comment: I'm using evaluateJavascript with a promise and a messageHandler and it works. Don't you just have issues with the strings your adding to the script without actually having quotes around them?
I think this should work: 
let js = "Promise.resolve('" + input + "').then(res => webkit.messageHandlers.bridge.postMessage({'i': '" + String(self.i) + "', 'data': res}))"